# Impersonate a user in a new tab in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, flow-router

I have one big application, with an admin side and a end-user side.  I've had the ability for the admins to impersonate a user within the same broswer/tab for a long time now.

I'd now like to change it up a bit; I'd like the admin to be able to click the impersonate user button and be taken to a new tab and be logged in as that user in the new tab -- but all the while the tab the admin came from must still be logged in as it was.

This is my impersonate user Meteor method:

```
  'click #impersionate-user': (event, instance) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (Session.get('accountId')) {
      Meteor.call('impersonate', Session.get('accountId'), (error, id) => {
        if (error) throw new Meteor.Error(error);
        Session.setPersistent('accountIdBeforeImpersionation', id); // persists accross page refresh
        Meteor.connection.setUserId(id);
        FlowRouter.go('user.dashboard.view');
      });
    }
  }
});
```

If I open a new window using something like this:

```
const win = window.open(FlowRouter.route('/case-details'), '_blank');
win.focus();
```

How can I control what user to log in as, how can I pass the user to log in as from one tab to the next?

Comment: I don't think you can be logged into/impersonate two separate accounts in separate tabs at the same time

Comment: I got this working just fine.  I have an admin tab open, and impersonate a "user" in another tab.